# Change colour of textView placeholder

Tags: swift, cosmicmind

I am using a [material design library](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material) for ios but i didn't found any property on how to change it's placeholder colour when there is no data entered. I have to use a standard background and the placeholder is not visible if it's gray

Comment: Why material design? That's Android UI, not iOS.

Comment: Client wants web, ios and android to have similar design. And because the web was first and uses material, everything else has to be material. Also that library is great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an attributed string for this:

```
let attrString = NSAttributedString(string: "Text", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blueColor()])
myTextField.attributedPlaceholder = attrString
```

Answer (score 1):

Version 1.34.5 allows the textField placeholder text color to be set like so:

```
textField.placeholderTextColor = MaterialColor.grey.base
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ATKit.

Refer: https://aurvan.github.io/atkit-ios-release/index.html

ATTextView Class: https://aurvan.github.io/atkit-ios-release/helpbook/Classes/ATTextView.html

Code:

```
import ATKit

@IBOutlet weak var messageTextView :ATTextView!

self.messageTextView.placeholderColor = UIColor(red: 173.0/255.0, green: 216.0/255.0, blue: 230.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

Screenshot:

[image: ATTextView Placeholder Screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material/issues/169

See issue 169 on this. Release [1.34.0](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material/releases/tag/1.34.0) includes this ability.

EDIT

New code in Material library is
`textField.placeholderTextColor = MaterialColor.green.base`